# Overriding equals for only one method

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I had overridden equals for an object class so that every time a duplicate occurred when adding objects of that class to an array list, a dialogue box would pop up. But this pops up with the remove() for array list. Is there a way I can make this conditional based on which method uses equals? Like two different equals, or maybe use another array list method that can let you specify which equals to use?

Edit:
Sorry about being very unclear with my question. 
Here's my overridden equals and hashcode methods:

```
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object s) {
    if(!(s instanceof Car)) {
    return false;
}

    Car s2  = (Car)s;
    if(this.name.equals(s2.name) && this.ride.equals(s2.ride)){
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Delete Item");
        alert.setHeaderText(
        "Are you sure?");
         alert.showAndWait();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    int hashC;

    hashC = name.hashCode();
    hashC *= ride.hashCode();
    return hashC;
}
```

As for the rest, I use the HashSet to remove duplicates automatically.

Comment: Showing your code is the best way to trace the bugs out

Comment: @Hemlata have you read the full question ?

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates use set. The equals method is not used when adding elements in the list so overriding it has no use, the reason remove() is displaying the dialog box is because remove() uses equals method for comparison, when remove(object) method is used.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear. We need to see the code that you are having problems with.  If the dialog is popping up for `remove()`, something in your code has to be making that happen.

Comment: Please review this [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make `equals` do anything more than what the [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) says it should do. Instead, use a check for [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) to see if the element already exists in the `List`.

```
if (list.indexOf(object) != -1) {
    dialog.show();
} else {
    list.add(object);
}
```

If you don't want the collection to contain any duplicates and you don't care about the order of elements, however, you should be using a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of a `List`. This will automatically keep out duplicates by checking `equals`, and will return false on the [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) method when a duplicate exists. You will need to override the [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) method on your object also.

```
if (!set.add(object)) {
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I tried too hard with keeping my old code despite the later flaws that cropped up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MohSel You may want to look up the MVC design pattern, which decouples the user interface from the underlying data structures. In general, UI code shouldn't be found in a class like `Car`.